# Error in "pdfetch" in R

Tags: r

I want to fetch historical stock prices from Yahoo finance with "pdfetch" package for a series of tickers,this is my code:

```
d1<-pdfetch_YAHOO(identifiers[1:636], c("high","low","close","volume"),
                  from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = "2016-01-30")
```

but I received this message:

```
Error in (function (..., all = TRUE, fill = NA, suffixes = NULL, join = "outer", : unsupported data type
```

it is working, when I fetch the prices of high low and close.

any idea about it?

I saved the 636 tickers in identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in version 0.2.1 and is available in CRAN now.

Answer (score 1):

To parameter is not Date.
Can you try it:

```
d1<-pdfetch_YAHOO(identifiers[1:636], c("high","low","close","volume"),
              from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-01-30"))
```

Another problem may be your identifiers vector.
Can you show output of identifiers?

Comment: It doesn't work. identifiers[1:5]
[1] "000001.SZ" "000553.SZ" "000717.SZ" "000718.SZ" "000788.SZ"          class(identifiers)
[1] "character"

Comment: When I tried with 1 identifier, it worked:

pdfetch_YAHOO("000001.SZ", c("high","low","close","volume"),
              from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-01-30"))

With multi identifiers:

pdfetch_YAHOO(c("000001.SZ", "000553.SZ"), c("high","low","close","volume"),
              from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-01-30"))

It worked again.
I think there is a problem with your identifiers table, again.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is just working for 2 tickers, I tried for 3 tickers and more but It doesn't work. thank you for your comment.I want to calculate Money flow index for each company and put all of them in a matrix. so I need to have all of the prices in one table

Comment: This problem reflected a bug in which the volume column was read as character instead of numeric. Version 0.2.0, available on CRAN shortly, fixes this.